# Can't do pattern matching properly

Tags: scala

I have difficulties in pattern matching for data received from a server:

```
scala> res
res9:Option[List[Any]] = Some(List(Some(List(Some(1))), Some(List(Some(2))), Some(List(Some(3))), Some(List(Some(4)))))

scala> res match {
     |   case x:Option[List[Any]] => println("yes")
     |   case _ => println("no")
     | }

yes
```

Yes, no error, but what I really want to do is:

```
res match {
  case Some(List(
    Some(List(Some(a: Int))),
    Some(List(Some(b: Int))),
    Some(List(Some(c: Int))),
    Some(List(Some(d: Int)))
  )) => println(s"yessss, a: $a; b: $b; c: $c; d: $d")

  case _ => println("no")
}
```

And here is says "no" for some reason.

Comment: Probably just use a proper data structure and for-comprehension instead of this big ball of mud?

Comment: @Mef, it's not a data structure I'm allowed to pick. It's gotten from a server.

Comment: Works for me, probably you use the wrong REPL variable in the match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your life easier by defining your own [extractor object](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112) that corresponds to the data you're working with:

```
object Test extends App {
  object My {
    def unapply(x: Any): Option[Int] =
      x match {
        case Some(List(Some(a: Int)))   => Some(a)
        case _                          => None
      }
  }
```

Now matching on your example can be much shortened:

```
  val res : Option[List[Any]] = Some(List(Some(List(Some(1))),
                                          Some(List(Some(2))),
                                          Some(List(Some(3))),
                                          Some(List(Some(4)))))

  res match {
    case Some(List(My(a), My(b), My(c), My(d))) =>
       println(s"yessss, a: $a; b: $b; c: $c; d: $d")

    case _ => println("no")
  }
}
```